# Unique identifier for each list of list in data frame

Tags: python

I have a list of list,

```
lst = [[2, 0, 1, 6, 7, 8], [4, 3, 5]]
```

and I want to flatten the list and assign a unique id to each list in the list merged into a data.frame.

Desired output:

```
  value group
0   2   0
1   0   0
2   1   0
3   6   0
4   7   0
5   8   0
6   4   1
7   3   1
8   5   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [[2, 0, 1, 6, 7, 8], [4, 3, 5]] 

final_list = []
for i, l in enumerate(lst):
    for num in l:
        final_list.append({'value': num, 'group': i})

df = pd.DataFrame(final_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to do some fancy flattening:

```
flattened = [(item, index) for index, sublist in enumerate(lst) for item in sublist]
df = pd.DataFrame(flattened, columns=['value','group'])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
new_lst = []
for group in lst:
    for n in group:
        new_lst.append({"group":lst.index(group),"value": n})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something before asking for desired output.

Looping through a list of list, whilst having a unique identifier, you may want to use the function enumerate that "gives the indexer" of the list.

```
for i,sub_list in enumerate(lst):
    identifier = i
    [(value,identifier) for value in sublist]
    ....
```

Hoping this will help